# Change the default axios base url in vuex store actions fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework

I would like to change the default baseUrl in my vuex actions.

So in my configiration i have

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
   baseURL: appdetails.apiurl
})

axiosInstance.interceptors .....

export {axiosInstance}
```

So in my quasar store am simply calling

```
import { axiosInstance } from '../../../plugins/axios'

function getAverages (context) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return axiosInstance.get("average-items")
        .then((res) => {
            ......//other stuff
        })
   })
}
```

In the store the above works

But now am in a situation where i would like to change the baseUrl from the imported axiosInstance How do i proceed.

So i have tried. In the vuex action i have

```
function getAppValues (context, { baseUrl, apiurl}) {
  let fetchreq = axiosInstance.get("test");
  if (baseUrl){
    fetchreq = axiosInstance.get({ url: apiurl, baseURL: baseUrl });
   }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fetchreq
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("res is", res);
            resolve(true)
        },(err)=>{
            console.log("err is e", err);
        })
  })

}
```

So in my component am calling

```
 this.$store.dispatch("app/getAppValues",{baseUrl:'https://test.com',apiurl:'test'});
```

But now am getting an error

```
res is TypeError: request.url.indexOf is not a function
at eval
```

Also when i dont pass baseUrl like `this.$store.dispatch("app/getAppValues")` but am getting an error

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined. Even when the request is an error it still resolves as a response
```

How do i resolve this and at the same time check if baseUrl is passed in my store action request